# Math.random vs other random algorithms

Tags: node.js, debugging, prng, native-methods, random-seed

I'm using a node.js client application to fuzz a remote server.

I can ~100% of the time crash the remote server when using Math.random in the node.js client. However, I've since tried a couple of deterministic, seeded random number generators, and neither are able to crash it.

I suspect its due to an idiosyncrasy of Math.random or the seeded generators I've tested.

This is one of the seeded generators I've tried:

```
var x = 123456789, y = 362436069, z = 521288629, w = 88675123;
function random() { // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6275875
    var t;
    t = x ^ (x << 11);
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    return (w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8)))/(4294967296/2);
}
```

In what way will the output be different to Math.random()? Also, why does 2^32, 4294967296, need to be divided by 2?

Comment: `Math.random` crashes the server? You sure have some other issues

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I know, but to debug the server, I'd ideally like a deterministic test case. Hence trying to have deterministic "random" numbers.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's not the code inside the generator that will crash the server, it will be the effect of the return value to the rest of your code. So a simple `for`-loop, iterating all possible values between 0 and 1.0 should be enough to crash it too.

Comment: Can you show us the code that's using the random number?
Unless you've overwritten `Math.random` (Which'd be a **very** stupid thing to do), I doubt it's that specific function crashing the server.

Answer (score 0):

> In what way will the output be different to Math.random()?

Math.random uses an implicit engine specific algorithm which has no seeding capability, whereas your implementation is platform independent and explicitly seeded.

> Also, why does 2^32, 4294967296, need to be divided by 2?

It is used to ensure a multiple of two, so the random number generator does not fail on an odd number.

**References**

- [JavaScript Random Numbers](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-randm.htm)
- [JavaScript Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_crypto)
- [Better Random Numbers for JavaScript](https://github.com/nquinlan/better-random-numbers-for-javascript-mirror)
- [Some Bugs in JavaScript Implementations](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-flaws.htm)
- [Node Alea PRNG Module](https://github.com/coverslide/node-alea)
- [curand generator fails on odd number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561988/curand-generator-fails-on-odd-number-of-elements)